# Start application rotate of 90 degrees

Tags: qt, windows-ce

Is there anyway to start the application rotate of 90 degrees? I read about qt-gfx-transformed, but it seems to be only for the Qt embedded linux and I am on Windows ce. Any suggestion?

Thanks